# Simple adding two arrays using numpy in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This might be a simple question. However, I wanted to get some clarifications of how the following code works.

```
a = np.arange(8)
a
array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
Example Function = a[0:-1]+a[1:]/2.0
```

In the Example Function, I want to draw your attention to the plus sign between the array `a[0:-1]+a[1:]`. How does that work? What does that look like?

For instance, is the plus sign (addition) adding the first index of each array? (e.g `1+2`) or add everything together? (e.g `1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5+5+6+6+7`)

Then, I assume `/2.0` is just dividing it by `2`...

Answer (score 10):

A numpy array uses vector algebra in that you can only add two arrays if they have the same dimensions as you are adding element by element

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 b = [1,1,1]
 a+b # will throw an error
```

whilst

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 b = [1,1,1,1,1]
 a+b # is ok
```

The division is also element by element.

Now to your question about the indexing

```
 a      = [1,2,3,4,5]
 a[0:-1]= [1,2,3,4]
 a[1:]  = [2,3,4,5]
```

or more generally `a[index_start: index_end]` is inclusive at the `start_index` but exclusive at the `end_index` - unless you are given a `a[start_index:]`where it includes everything up to and including the last element.

My final tip is just to try and play around with the structures - there is no harm in trying different things, the computer will not explode with a wrong value here or there. Unless you trying to do so of course.

Answer (score 1):

If arrays have identical shapes, they can be added:

```
new_array = first_array.__add__(second_array)
```

This simple operation adds each value from first_array to each value in  second_array and puts result into new_array.